# Shiro AOP with GUICE not working

Tags: aop, guice, shiro, guice-servlet

I am writing a service in which i use Shiro for security. I have also incorporated Guice with it. I create the GUICE injector in a `GuiceServletContextListener` :

```
//Custom Shiro Web module with defined REALM
new MyShiroWebModule(this.servletContext, "/v1/*"),

//Shiro annotations
new MyAOPModule(),
```

I also bind the Guice Container and GuiceShiroFilter in the `JerseyServletModule`:

```
serve("/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);                  
//Adds Shiro filtering  
MyShiroWebModule.bindGuiceFilter(binder());
```

But the Annotations from Shiro just don't seem to work!

I configure the chains in `MyShiroWebModule`:

```
addFilterChain("/v1/res/test", ANON);
addFilterChain("/v1/**", ROLES, AUTHC_BASIC);
```

So if I use the "ROLES" filter then it scans for roles in the AOP manner of:

`@RolesAllowed("SomeFancyRole")` (SEE EDIT)

But i would like to leverage the GUICE Shiro AOP functionality. I have tried the base ShiroAOPModule instead of my own -> my is for debug to see if the configuration is called.

`@User, @Authenticated etc.`

How can I incorporate this functionality as the documentation states that only "adding" the ShiroAOPModule should work out of the box?
Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Turns out that the `@RolesAllowed` is working thanks to adding:

`params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_RESOURCE_FILTER_FACTORIES,                          "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory");`

in the JerseyServletModule

`serve("/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);`

So the AOP from Shiro is still not filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it for the standard ShiroAopModule class. It has to be initialized after your ShiroWebModule subclass.
This is a snippet to make the ServletModule work with Jersey 1.18.1, Guice 3 and Apache Shiro 1.2.3

```
public class BootstrapServletModule extends ServletModule{

private static final String propertyPackages= GenericBootstrapConstants.JERSEY_PROPERTY_PACKAGES;

@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    super.configureServlets();

    //get the bootstrapping Properties file
    install(new BootstrapPropertiesModule());

    //Initialize Persistence JPA Unit of Work if present
    //install(new MyUnitOfWorkModule());
    //Initialize Apache Shiro if present
    install(new BootstrapShiroModule(getServletContext()));
    //This allows Shiro AOP Annotations http://shiro.apache.org/java-authorization-guide.html
    install(new ShiroAnnotationsModule());

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, propertyPackages);
    //if you had a Persistence Service like JPA Unit of Work you would need to add this PersistFilter also.
    //filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
    //if you had a ShiroWebModule installed above you would need to add this GuiceShiroFilter also.
    filter("/*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);
    serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);

}
}
```

Regards

Comment: You can check a sample project here
[https://github.com/pabiagioli/shiro-guice-jersey-bootstrap](https://github.com/pabiagioli/shiro-guice-jersey-bootstrap)